# Beamer: Enumerate across multiple frames?

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I am using beamer, I would like to know how to use

```
\begin{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

in two frames and without re-starting the count.

Obviously we can't use

```
    \begin{frame}
       \begin{enumerate}
          \item
          \item 
    \end{frame}
          
    \begin{frame}
    \item 
    \item 
    
    \end{enumerate}
 \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do this maybe ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{2}
\item 
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{4}
\item
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```